# Why doesn't Solve work unless I request a solution for both unknowns?

Tags: equation-solving

I have two circuit equations

```
power == voltage*current
voltage == resistance*current
```

You can plug the second equation into the first and get

```
power == current^2 * resistance
```

I'm wondering why this input is returning no solution

```
Solve[{power == voltage*current, voltage == resistance*current}
  /. {voltage -> 5, resistance -> 10}, current]
```

If I manually solve for `power`, then I can get the correct result

```
Solve[{power == voltage*current, voltage == resistance*current}
  /. {voltage -> 5, resistance -> 10, power -> 5^2/10}, current]

{{current -> 1/2}}
```

I also get the correct solution if I request the solution for *both* `current` and `power`

```
Solve[{power == voltage*current, voltage == resistance*current}
   /. {voltage -> 5, resistance -> 10}, {current, power}]

{{current -> 1/2, power -> 5/2}}
```

I did some more testing and found that if I provide the `MaxExtraConditions->All` that I get a solution. Is this what I should be using?

```
{{current -> ConditionalExpression[1/2, power == 5/2]}}
```

Comment: The issue is that unless you solve for `power`, it is assumed to be a parameter of the equations. And the equations do not have solutions for arbitrary values of `power`, hence nothing is returned (`Solve` normally only returns generic solutions as mentioned in the documentation) - as you've realized, `MaxExtraConditions->All` can help with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't read your mind to understand that `power` is a free variable rather than a parameter you intend to define later. One way to deal with this is to solve for both `current` and `power`. Another way is to simplify by eliminating `power`:

```
Eliminate[{power == voltage*current, voltage == resistance*current}, power]
(* voltage == current resistance *)
```

Then, solve that.

Comment: Or eliminate `power` with `Solve` using this form: `Solve[{power == voltage*current, 
    voltage == resistance*current} /. {voltage -> 5, 
    resistance -> 10}, current, {power}][[1]]`